# Login failed for user SQL Server 2012 Pentaho

Tags: authentication, sql-server-2012, database-connection, pentaho

I setted the sql server driver into pentaho software.
I have the following connection error:

[image]

My user and password is corret.
Can you help me?

EDIT: My Configuration

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the database connection settings?

Comment: It's a normal DB connection. I'm able to ping the ip address so it's correct. It's everything fine cause I can connect to my DB in Visual Studio. I'm really angry cause when you don't use a correlated Microsoft Tecnology , everything doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure you selected the correct database driver, and settings.

Comment: I put the sql server driver into \data-integration\lib. I downloaded the jar from microsoft web site and i downloaded the following drivers:   sqljdbc4 , sqljdbc_auth , sqljdbc. However, I edited my first post with configuration.